# keep selected option from an automatic added dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I encounter problem on keeping the selected option from an automatic added dropdown. Whenever I go to edit page the selected option there is the last option in the dropdown. I am only using PHP on this. See code below (edit page):

```
$optionQuery = "SELECT * FROM option_list";
$optionResult = mysqli_query($con, $optionQuery);
          
if(mysqli_num_rows($optionResult) > 0) { 
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($optionResult)) {
        $selected = "";
        if ($row['option'] == $option) {
           $selected = " selected";
        }
        echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['option']) . '"' . $selected . '>' 
        . htmlspecialchars($row['option'])
        . '</option>';
    }
}
```

Add page

```
<label for="" class="form-label">Store Name</label>
<select type="text" name="store" class="form-select" id="" autocomplete="off">
    <option selected hidden></option>
    <?php
       $optionQuery = "SELECT * FROM option_list";
       $optionResult = mysqli_query($con, $optionQuery);

       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($optionResult)) {
             echo '<option value="'. $row['option'] .'">'. $row['option'] .'</option>';
       }
     ?>
</select>
```

I want to achieve that the selected option will be the one that keeps selected not the last option all the time. Thank you so much for your help!

Or maybe other language that could resolve this?

Comment: Looks like that should be working, but we can't tell for sure, because we don't know what your variables actually contain. So this is the point where _you_ should do some basic debugging.